# Drupal taking out $ sign when querying

Tags: php, mysql, drupal-7

I am trying to query a table that has a column name called timestamp$sec. This is a third party database that I am trying to connect to . So I cannot change their design. when I am running this query directly into mysql it works fine

```
SELECT timestamp$sec from table A
```

but when I am querying it from inside drupal site. It throws me this error

```
PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column &#039;timestampsec&#039; in &#039;field list&#039;
```

Noticed that timestamp$sec is now converted into timestampsec and hence this error message.

This error is coming from this

```
PagerDefault->execute() (line 79 of C:\project\includes\pager.inc)
```

Why is drupal changing my column name and how can I fix it?

Comment: show the actual line 79. probably you're doing `->exec("blahblah$sec")`, and $sec is being treated as a php variable. most likely `->exec("blahblah\$sec")` would fix the problem.

Comment: `$query = db_select('tableA', 'tA')->extend('PagerDefault');
 $query ->fields('TA', array('Power','timestamp$sec')
        );
 $result = $query->limit(25)->execute();`

Comment: well, try `timestamp\$sec` in there, or even `\\$sec` and see if that helps any. no idea what drupal would be doing internally when it's building the query.

Comment: @MarcB Single quotes do not parse PHP variables. Additonally, the 'sec' component still appears in the error message. It does appear that the drupal adapter removes a dollar symbol.

Comment: no, they don't, but who knows what drupal's doing internally. could be `eval()` in the chain somewhere.

Comment: @MarcB i  have tried imestamp\$sec . It doesn't work. Somwhere drupal is removing the $ symbol.

Comment: try bypassing drupal entirely and issue a query directly via pdo/mysqli, see if the same thing happens there. I don't know what drupal's using internally, but at least doing direct would eliminate drupal from the list of possible sources of this problem.

Comment: @MarcB if I query it directly it works. I have tried it already. Its inside the drupal thats causing this.

Comment: I'm thinking this might be more of a drupal question. Where in the drupal jungle does this code exist? What kind of drupal construct is wrapped around it?

Comment: @BigScar I will share this with drupal community.. Thank you all for your suggestions

Answer (score 0):

> show the actual line 79. probably you're doing ->exec("blahblah$sec"), and $sec is being treated as a php variable. most likely ->exec("blahblah\$sec") would fix the problem. 
>   #

not real because then it would be `timestamp`
`sec` is no more string and 
#

I dont thing $ is allowed as fieldname char!

But try ` around the hole field `timestamp$sec`, may the will do it.